# How do I lose my wanted level in co-op?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I play co-op with a partner who frequently causes trouble for the police and rival gangs.  (I, of course, am a perfect little angel who drives courteously and wouldn't dream of being inconsiderate to others.)  Whenever one of us (him, clearly) gets a wanted level with the police or a gang, we can't figure out how to get rid of it.

In the single player game, I can hide out in a business that I own, and as soon as I enter my wanted level immediately goes away.  I tried this in co-op and it didn't work - the enemies just followed me inside.

What do we have to do to get rid of our wanted level?  Do we both need to be inside a building that we both own?  Can we be in different buildings, as long as we both own the one we're in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did some experimentation today, and concluded that both players must be in an owned building (ie, a shop or crib) and then the wanted level resets.

It doesn't have to be the same building, but you both have to own wherever you're hiding.

This is easiest with the cribs that you unlock early in the campaign (such as Shaundi's Ex's Loft), since they don't have to be bought and are almost always available to every player.